# Notation of star before an ayah indicates?

Tags: arabic, reading-quran

In this list of verses in surah 42 http://quran.com/42/7-16, 13 is started with a star, what does it indicate?

[image]

I don't think it is marking a break of ruku, because in my Qur'an ruku ends at verse number 9 and a new ruku starts from 10. So, what is this star about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star notation, called *rubʿ l-hizb*, marks the starting of a *quarter* hizb.

*Hizb* being one of the two groups (plural: *ahzab*) a Juz' is divided into.

Sources:

- [Verse Marks](http://corpus.quran.com/documentation/versemarks.jsp)
- [Juz'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juz%27)
- [Rub el Hizb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rub_el_Hizb)

Comment: learned something today. :)